# How can I get past the invisible barrier on the edges of the map in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been trying to find a good answer, but most are videos (I can't watch) or don't work. I'm looking for a way to glitch through the invisible barrier that tells that you can't go any farther.

Has anyone done this on Xbox 360? I don't have any extension packs or mods installed if this helps in answering.

Comment: do... do you expect to *explore the other provinces* by bypassing the barrier? Or do you just want to get on the other side for kicks and giggles?

Comment: I would think that there's an invisible barrier there because beyond what you can see, the world doesn't exist, so I can't see how glitching through would produce any useful results.  

However, instead of asking someone else to do the work, perhaps you could reword the question asking if anyone has ever managed to do that, and if so, to give some tips on how to reproduce the actions, not dictating how the walkthrough should be.

Comment: You should reword your question for posterity's sake.  That would help other, future, users who have the same question.  At that, as the others here have informed you, your first concern is how to get past the invisible barrier.  Whether there is anything else beyond the barrier is another, different, question — one which, when you get a useful answer, you should be fully empowered to answer yourself!  I'd do it, but I've got this old wound in my knee . . .

Answer (score 13):

Edit your skyrim.ini file and add this as a new line under the `[General]` section to disable the invisible wall at the edge of Skyrim:

```
bBorderRegionsEnabled=0
```

I don’t know whether it’s possible to do this on the Xbox 360. On Windows, I think skyrim.ini is usually in your documents, in the “My Games/Skyrim” folder.

If you can’t edit skyrim.ini on the Xbox 360, you could perhaps try to use the [wooden plate glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8teW5icV0k) to travel through the border region. It works on city walls, but I don’t know whether it works on the border regions.

Prepare to be mildly disappointed: there is nothing much out there. You’ll find a few trees, and then mountains and ocean. The world will lose detail and you’ll eventually reach an endless ocean with nothing in it.

Mods occasionally place things outside those border regions, but in the vanilla game, you won’t find anything much out there.

Comment: Note that the things mods place out there are generally control items - "objects" that exist in game to only perform some function for the mod. They aren't meant to be played around with by your in-game character.

Comment: @Robotnik I didn’t know about those—thanks. I was thinking of mods like [Folkstead](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/58331/?), a mod which I sadly cannot recommend because of its dreadful voice acting, but it places a settlement just past the borders of Skyrim.

Answer (score 1):

In Skyrim for the XBox 360, there is a way to get past the invisible barrier.

All you have to do is go to the one near Falkreath. You can get past these using no mods. (I am using Hearthfire as it seems to work better.) You should note that after you pass the barrier, your followers will stop and wait. You won't be able to access them after this. Make sure you have a horse as it works better and is easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have not played in a while but when I did play on 360, I was able to find spots, that with the right jumping and turning, you could get past the boundries.  I have found low rez trees that feel like a fun house mirror of trees closely placed and spinning as you pass.  These were in a mountain area that required you to do a lot of jumping up the mountain and slipping back down to get around.  I wish there was something in there to find.  but it did allow me to access other areas of the game.  I found a half built castle with no doors but walls you could walk through.  i found a hole in the ground that you could fall through for kicks.  i found spots where i could shoot but not be hit.  if seeing behind the scences is interesting to you, then it can be worth the time.
requires a lot of saves to make sure you don't get caught in a glitch.

Answer (score -3):

I've heard that east of the bloodlet crown, south east of helgen there is a gap in the barier you can get through but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Despite there not being an actual gap (as far as I could explore) there is a perfect view of Cyrodill fro the SW of Bloodlet Throne.